# What is the best way to expose a List<T> as readonly?

Tags: c#

I've been around this design problem many times, and never found a killer solution.

I want to expose a collection that is editable in the owner `class` scope, but only readable for other public scopes.

**Trial 1:**

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<object> _myList = new List<object>();

    public IEnumerable<object> MyList { get { return _myList; } }
}
```

The problem with this is a external code can just cast it back to `List` and edit, like this:

```
var x = ((List<object>)MyList);
```

**Trial 2:**

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<object> _myList = new List<object>();

    public IEnumerable<object> MyList { get { return _myList.ToList(); } }
}
```

This way we prevent external modification, but create a unnecessary overhead of copying the `List` many times.

**Trial 3:**

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<object> _myList = new List<object>();
    private ReadOnlyCollection<object> _roList = 
        new ReadOnlyCollection<object>(_myList)

    public IEnumerable<object> MyList { get { return _roList; } }
}
```

This is the standard solution, wich I use currently, but `ReadOnlyCollection` is about 30% slower:

```
Debug Trace:
Use normal foreach on the ReadOnlyCollection
Speed(ms): 2520,3203125
Result: 4999999950000000

use<list>.ForEach
Speed(ms): 1446,1796875
Result: 4999999950000000

Use normal foreach on the List
Speed(ms): 1891,2421875
Result: 4999999950000000
```

Is there a 'perfect' way of doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried returning the enumerator?

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<object> _myList = new List<object>();

    public IEnumerable<object> MyList { get { yield return _myList.GetEnumerator(); } }
}
```

This doesn't create a copy, is readonly, and cannot be cast back to list.

**Edit:** this only works with *yield* return. It is lazy evaluated this way, I do not know whether that is an issue for you or not.

Comment: Yes. It won't compile, or I'm doing it wrong: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>.Enumerator' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>'

Comment: I don't have access to a compiler right now but I've seen this work before. I probably have syntax wrong.

Comment: Forgive me, if I'm doing it wrong again, but it compiles only if the return type is IEnumerable<object> or IEnumerable. Right? Or it can be strongly typed?

Comment: It has to be an `IEnumerable` for this to work, if that's what you mean. If you mean that it's an `IEnumerable` of something other than `object`, then you can do that as well. As long as the underlying collection is of that type.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`List<T>.AsReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx) method to expose a thin read-only wrapper of your list. There will be no additional copying, and the caller will "see" changes to the original array done inside your method instantaneously:

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<object> MyList { get { return _myList.AsReadOnly(); } }
```

Comment: I think this will still run into the performance problem the OP has with ReadOnlyCollection.

Comment: I just tried. It's even slower => 
Use normal foreach on the List.AsReadOnly |
Speed(ms): 2771,296875 |
Result: 4999999950000000
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`List<T>` implements `IReadOnlyList<T>`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<object> _myList = new List<object>();   // Modifiable

    public IReadOnlyList<object> MyList => _myList;      // Read only
}
```

Comment: I believe this code is good for internal projects. The only issue is that the caller could cast the `IReadOnlyList<object>` back into a regular `List<object>` and modify it again. Therefore, I wouldn't suggest this code if the project is a publicly shared library.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I usually use and like a lot because it is simple is the following one:

```
public IEnumerable<object> MyList { get { return _myList.Select(x => x); } }
```

However, it requires you to use a version of .NET that supports Linq

For looping over it with a `foreach` it's actually faster: less than 1ms for the `Select` and 0.1 second for the `ReadOnlyCollection`. For the `ReadOnlyCollection`, I used:

```
public IEnumerable<object> MyROList { get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<object>(_myList); } }
```

Comment: In my tests it was slower. How you did it? => Use normal foreach on the List.Select(x => x) |
Speed(ms): 4216,5234375 |
Result: 4999999950000000

Comment: I don't know what you test in your foreach. I just call a dummy foreach like that: `foreach (var a in foo.MyList) { }`. Same for the `ReadOnlyCollection`. Each of the loop test I made is wrapped within a `StopWatch` to calculate the time required.

Comment: The same test using the `yield` proposed in another answer gives me results slightly faster than my solution. But the difference is around 0.01ms for 10 million items.

Comment: I sum all long values from 1 to 100,000,000 on a x64 machine

Comment: Indeed it's slower when summing up. 2417ms for my solution. `ReadOnlyCollection` takes 1000ms. I get 236ms and 94ms for 10 million items. 27ms and 10ms for 1 million.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` as a wrapper - it uses your `List<T>` collection internally (using the same reference, so it doesn't copy anything, and any changes made to the List are also reflected in the ReadOnlyCollection).

It's better than just offering an IEnumerable property because it also offers indexing and count information.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework 4.5 introduces two new interfaces: [`IReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881542.aspx) and [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385.aspx). `List<T>` implements both interfaces.

Comment: I guess is the same case as the IEnumerable. It is possible to cast it back to List, and modify.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [`List<T>.AsReadOnly` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx), see the code snippet below:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private List<object> _myList = new List<object>();

    public IList<object> MyList { get { return _myList.AsReadOnly(); } }
}
```